# Pivot on a column with the same values

Tags: t-sql

Sorry difficult to match my question to see if it is similar to another, anyhow. My table is:

```
X|SCType|SCName
---------------
1|SC1   |Bob
1|SC1   |Jane
1|SC2   |Mary
2|SC3   |Karl
```

The result I want is:

```
X|SCTYpe|SCName1|SCName2|SCName3
1|SC1   |Bob    |Jane   |NULL
1|SC2   |Mary   |NULL   |NULL
2|SC3   |Karl   |NULL   |NULL
```

I assume in T-sql sql-server 2014 I need to use a pivot query however I cannot figure out what to pivot on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have come up with my own answer:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT X, SCType, SCName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X, SCTYpe ORDER BY X, SCType) AS XTypeRow
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT X, SCType, [1] AS [SCName1], [2] AS [SCName2], [3] AS [SCName3]
FROM CTE
PIVOT (
  MAX(SCName)
  FOR XTypeRow IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS p
```